# html button for mysql database backup and send to gmail

Tags: html, mysql

i have researched that doing backup and restoring mysql databases is done through phpmyadmin.
I just want to ask, is it possible to have a button in a webpage that will let the user automatically backup a database and send it to his/her desired email account? the backup will be in a zip file.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of things

1) phpMyAdmin is just a GUI to manage a mysql database. Basically just a user friendly way to interact with the db without having to use command line.

2)What you want to do is certainly possible in various ways.
You need some sort of server. If you are new to programming  you could use an apache server and php as backend technology ( use xampp for a ready to use hosting environment ).
Basically the tasks are the following :
1)Serve a webpage with a button
2)On click of button call another page that connects to the db, backs it up, saves the backup to disk and then emails it. I'm sure there are lots of examples on the web, just make a quick google search :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to do that with php or any other server side language which have a functions to deal with MySQL or any type of database

Answer (score 1):

You can program it , here is a good answer on that 
[Stakeoverflow question](https://dzone.com/articles/backup-mysql-database-and-send) &
[implementation from dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/backup-mysql-database-and-send)

Comment: you are welcome , let me know if you have any questions reagarding same

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code on github which could help you.https://github.com/tazotodua/useful-php-scripts/blob/master/export-mysql-database-sql-backup.php